# JS: json, dynamic method creature and closure

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry for not very clear title,but I don't know where the problem is.

So, I need to write a function which creates js objects from json and for fields which begins with underscore it must create setters and getters.

This is test json:

```
{
"_language":null,
"_country":null
}
```

This is the function I wrote

```
function jsonToObject(json){
    return JSON.parse(json,function(key,value){
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            return (function(value){
                var replacement = {};
                for (var k in value) {
                    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
                        //if this is private field 
                        if (k.lastIndexOf("_", 0) === 0){
                            replacement[k]=value[k];
                            var name=k.substring(1);
                            var getName="get"+name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                            replacement.constructor.prototype[getName]=function(){
                                return this[k];
                            };
                            var setName="set"+name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                            replacement.constructor.prototype[setName]=function(newValue){
                                this[k]=newValue;
                            };
                        //if this is public field
                        }else{
                            replacement[k]=value[k];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return replacement;
            }(value));
        }
        return value;
    });
}
```

This is how I test it:

```
var test1=jsonToObject(data);
test1.setLanguage("11");
console.log("Point A:"+test1.getLanguage());//ouput 11
var test2=jsonToObject(data);
test2.setLanguage("22");
console.log("Point B:"+test2.getLanguage())//output 22
console.log("Point C:"+test1.getLanguage());//output function (a){this[c]=a}
console.log("Point D:"+test2.getLanguage())//output 22
```

The problem is at point C - the output must be 11. However its output is function... (this code is after optimization, that's why it looks obfucated). Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setter and getter duplicate defined

```
function jsonToObject(json) {
    return JSON.parse(json, function (key, value) {
        if (value && typeof value === 'object') {
            return (function (value) {
                var replacement = {};
                for (var k in value) {
                    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(value, k)) {
                        //if this is private field 
                        if (k.lastIndexOf("_", 0) === 0) {
                            replacement[k] = value[k];
                            var name = k.substring(1);
                            var getName = "get" + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                            //
                            // check defined
                            //
                            console.log(replacement.constructor.prototype[getName]);
                            //
                            // if defined function, prevent override
                            //
                            if (!/function/.test(typeof replacement.constructor.prototype[getName])) {
                                replacement.constructor.prototype[getName] = function () {
                                    return this[k];
                                };
                            }
                            var setName = "set" + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
                            // check defined
                            console.log(replacement.constructor.prototype[setName]);
                            // if defined function, prevent override
                            if (!/function/.test(typeof replacement.constructor.prototype[setName])) {
                                replacement.constructor.prototype[setName] = function (newValue) {
                                    this[k] = newValue;
                                };
                            }
                            //if this is public field
                        } else {
                            replacement[k] = value[k];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return replacement;
            }(value));
        }
        return value;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But try `console.log(test1);` The output will be `Object { _language: null, _country: "11" }` .

Comment: I solved the problem this wrapping setting setters and getters in anonymous function -> as I understand we pass the value but not reference.